# What is the definition of "crossover" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

the text is:

"Joe Burrow, the Bengals quarterback, has achieved a crossover appeal that has invited comparisons to Joe Namath."

I thought of crossover to mean comparisons in this case, But it would be redumbdant with the word comparisons written afterwords, right? so what does it means: "crossover appeal" in this text?

Comment: Have you checked 'crossover' in a good dictionary, like Cambridge?

Comment: I think it's effectively a "domain-specific" aspect of American Football (some players successfully "cross over" from ***one*** type of American Football to the other). But I don't really know. It's not something *most* Anglophones would know about. I can't be bothered, but you might wanna check whether Joe Namath was known for successfully switching to the (presumably, more lucrative) alternative "football league".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I would also consider whether Burrow (who is reckoned to be 'cool', in a rock-star way, according to a brief Google search) is appealing to people who aren't normally (American) football fans.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm not familiar with the idea that "niche-famous" people might achieve "crossover" to "broad appeal celebrity". To me the usage always implies switching to *a different **specialist** field*. But surely the context of the article should make it obvious whether Burrow did in fact switch to a different football league. For my money, though, if *achieved a crossover appeal * actually means *achieved **broad-based celebrity status** [beyond one's original specialist area]* then I'd say it's either a "misuse" or it's a peculiar AmE usage that doesn't exist in BrE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is only one type of American football. They are talking about this player crossing over from his appeal as a football player to his appeal as a fashion influencer or as a cool dresser outside of the game of football.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that the 'from niche to wider' meaning might be more AmE than BrE. I have seen jazz musicians described as having 'crossover appeal' if their music appeals to people who don't normally listen to jazz, and that is arguably a wider segment of the music consuming public.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: In my experience, ["crossover jazz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_jazz) always implies moving beyond the traditional boundaries of jazz into some *specific* different musical category (whether that be folk, funk, or just "pop[ular]" music). But like I said, maybe at least *some* Americans think of "achieve crossover appeal" as meaning to become so popular you appeal to ***everyone*** (not just extending your appeal to include some other *group* of people). It does strike me as a bit odd, though.

Comment: As an AmE speaker *crossover appeal* here means to be appeal to people outside of the domain of football.  This tracks with bands or songs being marketed as having "crossover appeal" meaning that they appeal to people outside of their genres.